# python flask class definition syntax

Tags: python, class, object, flask

In python classes are defined like [this](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) **class ClassName:**, but can anyone explain to me what this means **class flask.Flask()** in the [flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask) and what is a flask object. Thanks

Comment: What in the first paragraph proceeding the link you provided to the Flask documentation is confusing you? Is it the syntax of how documentation is normally shown for instance?

Answer (score 4):

This is the documentation of the constructor of the class `Flask` in the module `flask`.  The documentation uses the syntax you'd usually use to instantiate a class rather than to define it.  The italic *class* only specifies that this is a class.

This is documentation, not source code!

Comment: The documentaion is therefore confusing as far as I'm concerned. Where is the document that explains the syntax of the documentation?

Comment: My question is, why do this in the documentation: 
class flask.Flask(import_name, static_path=None, static_url_path=None, static_folder='static', template_folder='templates', instance_path=None, instance_relative_config=False). 
why not this : 
    def __init__(self, import_name, static_path=None, static_url_path=None,
                 static_folder='static', template_folder='templates',
                 instance_path=None, instance_relative_config=False):

Comment: To actullay call this, you do `flask.Flask(...)`, so this is what they are documenting.  They put the word `class` in front to denote this as a class.  Seems pretty straight-forward to me.